# AngularJS - Change view based on user preferences

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an email app. It consists of an option to change the default settings. When it is clicked, the following partial view is loaded.

[image]

In this view, when the `Save changes` button is clicked, the values chosen by the user are saved in `$localStorage` using `ngStorage` like so:

`savePreferenceService.js`

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var savePreferenceService = function ($localStorage) {

        this.setPreferences = function (selectedLang, converse, selectedNumber, selectedNumberContact, reply, signature) {
            $localStorage.selectedLang = selectedLang;
            $localStorage.converse = converse;
            $localStorage.selectedNumber = selectedNumber;
            $localStorage.selectedNumberContact = selectedNumberContact;
            $localStorage.reply = reply;
            $localStorage.signature = signature;

            console.log($localStorage.selectedLang);
            console.log($localStorage.converse);
            console.log($localStorage.selectedNumber);
            console.log($localStorage.selectedNumberContact);
            console.log($localStorage.reply);
            console.log($localStorage.signature);
        }
  };    

      angular.module('iisEmail')
        .service ('savePreferenceService', ['$localStorage', savePreferenceService]);
}());
```

I have the following questions:

1) Is there a way to store values entered by the user (e.g. `selectedLang`, `converse`, `selectedNumber`) in a JSON file. I have no database.

2) If the user only changes a few preferences (e.g. `language` preference and `number of conversations per page` preference), all other preferences (e.g. `number of contacts per page` and `reply`) return a value of `undefined`. Is there a way to return the default values for the preferences that were not changed by the user?. Here is the JSON file that contains the `dropdown` menu `options` (e.g. `data.languages` contains all the `languages` the user can choose from) and default preferences, `data.userPreferences`.

`settings.json`

```
  {
        "data": {
            "languages": [
                "Afrikaans",
                "Albanian",
                "Arabic",
                "Armenian",
                "Basque",
                "Bengali",
                "Catalan",
                "Cambodian",
                "Chinese (Mandarin)",
                "German",
                "Greek",
                "Gujarati",
                "Hebrew",
                "Icelandic",
                "Maori",
                "Marathi",
                "Mongolian",
                "Serbian",
                "Slovak",
                "Slovenian",
                "Spanish",
                "Swahili",
                "Swedish",
                "Tamil",
                "Tatar",
                "Telugu"
            ],
            "undoSend": [
                5,
                10,
                20,
                30
            ],
            "conversations": [
                10,
                20,
                30,
                40,
                50,
                60,
                70,
                80,
                90,
                100
            ],
            "contacts": [
                20,
                40,
                60,
                80,
                100,
                120,
                130,
                140,
                180,
                200
            ],
            "userPreferences": {
                "selectedLang": "Telugu",
                "converse": false,
                "selectedNumber": 10,
                "selectedNumberContact": 20,
                "reply": false,
                "signature": "--"
            }
        }
    }
```

3) My final goal - In the settings page, if the user selects 20 conversations per page, then the next time `Inbox` is clicked I want to show only 20 emails. Right now, 50 emails are being displayed like so (`top-right` - It says `1-50 of 277`):

[image]

Does anyone have ideas regarding these questions?

**UPDATE - Question 1**

Looks like there is no way to store user entered data in a JSON file, so I am using `localStorage` to save it on the client-side.

**UPDATE - Question 3**

Here is a solution for question 3. I bound `$scope.conversation` property to `conversation` in the view. The value of `$scope.conversation` is set to the number selected by the user. This number is saved in `localStorage`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Gmail App</title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 50px;
        }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <script src="Vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Vendor/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body data-ng-app="iisEmail">
  <div class="container" data-ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Email <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Mail</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-click="loadView('settings')"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
            <!-- split button -->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    <div class="checkbox" style="margin: 0;">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   data-ng-click="selectAllEmail()"
                                   data-ng-model="checkAllEmail">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </button>

            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Refresh">
                Â Â Â <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>Â Â Â 
            </button>
            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    More <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Mark all as read</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="text-center"><small class="text-muted">Select messages to see more actions</small></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right" data-ng-controller = "settingsController">
                <span class="text-muted"><b>1</b>â€“<b data-ng-bind = "conversation" data-ng-cloak>{{conversation}}</b> of <b>277</b></span>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" role="button">COMPOSE</a>
            <hr/>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="" data-ng-repeat="item in leftMenu">
                    <a href="#"><span class="badge pull-right"> {{item.emailCount}}</span> {{item.name}} </a>
                </li>
                <!--<li><a href="#">Starred</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Important</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sent Mail</a></li>
                <li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox">
                    </span>Primary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                    Social</a></li>
                <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>
                    Promotions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus no-margin">
                    </span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div ui-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="app/main.js"></script>
<!--Services-->

<script src="app/services/commonApiService.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/savePreferenceService.js"></script>

<script src="app/services/fetchDataService.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/settingsController.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/emailViewController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`savePreferenceService.js`

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var savePreferenceService = function ($localStorage) {
        this.setPreferences = function (selectedLang, converse, selectedNumber, selectedNumberContact, reply, signature) {
            $localStorage.selectedLang = selectedLang;
            $localStorage.converse = converse;
            $localStorage.selectedNumber = selectedNumber;
            $localStorage.selectedNumberContact = selectedNumberContact;
            $localStorage.reply = reply;
            $localStorage.signature = signature;
        };
  };    

      angular.module('iisEmail')
        .service ('savePreferenceService', ['$localStorage', savePreferenceService]);
}());
```

`settingsController.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var settingController = function (fetchDataService, $scope, savePreferenceService, $localStorage) {
        $scope.url = 'app/mock/settings.json';
        $scope.save = {};

        fetchDataService.getContent($scope.url)
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.contacts = response.data.contacts;
                $scope.languages = response.data.languages;
                $scope.conversations = response.data.conversations;
                $scope.undoSend = response.data.undoSend;
                $scope.save = response.data.userPreferences;
            });

         $scope.setPreference = function () {
            savePreferenceService.setPreferences($scope.save.selectedLang, $scope.save.converse, $scope.save.selectedNumber, $scope.save.selectedNumberContact, $scope.save.reply, $scope.save.signature);
        };

        $scope.conversation = $localStorage.selectedNumber;
    };

    angular.module('iisEmail')
        .controller ('settingsController',
        ['fetchDataService', '$scope', 'savePreferenceService', '$localStorage', settingController]);
}());
```

Comment: please split your question in 3 separate questions and exclude every non-important part  It is just too much to read and to answer.

Comment: And also make plunker for good answers

Comment: @simon Thanks for your comment. I have updated my question.

Comment: Can use a free data service if you don't have a database. Can't access file system from browser scripts

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. Can you elaborate on free data service?

Comment: sure ... simple google search

Comment: Why you don't keep using the localStorage from the user? You can store JSON files there just fine (and it is fairly simple since you are already using ngStorage).

So for your question 1, I would just keep using localStorage.

For your second question, everytime the user changes settings, I would load the object from ngStorage as `oldSettings` and I would loop through the new settings JSON properties, always checking for valid values and setting in the `oldSettings`. Then just save the `oldSettings` back to localstorage

Comment: @GabrielPires That's exactly what I have been doing